# R -generating values within an interval with mean value

Tags: r

How can I generate a set of random values, in an interval [1:5], with mean value 1.8? I've tried sample but dont know how to include the mean value.. rpois keeps returning zero values

Comment: Do you want the underlying probability distribution to have a mean of 1.8 or does the sample have to meet that condition? 2. question: do you need a certain probability distribution?

Comment: just the sample has to have the mean value 1.8.. and it has to consist of integers only.

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about integers 1:5, then the Poisson is a reasonable choice. Just set lambda to 0.8 and add 1:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rpois(2000, 0.8) + 1
x <- x[x < 6]
mean(x)
#> [1] 1.784677
min(x)
#> [1] 1
max(x)
#> [1] 5
head(x, 30)
#> [1] 1 1 2 3 1 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 5 1 2 3 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 3 1
hist(x, breaks = 30)
```

[image]
If you want the mean to be *exactly* 1.8, then you're not truly taking a random sample, but it should be possible to switch a few numbers to get a set of more-or-less random numbers that meet your criteria:

```
x <- sample(c(2, x[-which(x == 1)[1:38]]))
mean(x)
#> [1] 1.8
```

If you want any real-numbered value, you could try the same trick with the gamma distribution:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rgamma(1000, 2, 2.5) + 1
mean(x)
#> [1] 1.794942
max(x)
#> [1] 4.918468
min(x)
#> [1] 1.013304
head(x, 30)
#>  [1] 1.332346 2.428303 2.385268 1.820325 2.554164 2.016216
#>  [7] 1.915227 1.459717 1.272409 1.334249 1.462368 1.578189
#> [13] 1.242602 2.069755 1.926223 2.134657 2.044341 1.637085
#> [19] 2.543066 2.249806 1.309245 1.388618 1.490084 1.550701
#> [25] 1.324007 1.115011 2.184496 1.408031 2.259906 2.032122
hist(x, breaks = 30)
```

[image]

It would be more difficult (though not impossible) to tweak some of these numbers to give a true mean of precisely 1.8.